# R - Handling character variables by matching values on the same prefix while truncating the diverging suffix in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

As I edited my question twice, I was asked to post a new question and align the example data better with my original data set to avoid editing the question afterwards.

I currently have a seemingly easy task, but as the data set is quite large, it is not feasible to do the task manually by hand.

The data.table stores one column of `name` (different legal entity) and numerous other columns storing data corresponding to that name object, say `var1`, `var2` and `var3`. The name variable is type character and the others are type numeric. Data examples are arbitrary and just for illustrative purposes.

---

Now to the question. Names can start the same (same prefix) but might end differntly (diverging suffix). Imagine for example plant species of different classes or company names with differnt legal entitity form. **The longest shared prefix should be retained.** The data below better illustrates what I want to achieve than the original question.

My generic question is, whether there is a simple method to match all values of the name variable that have the same prefix and assign them this "same" prefix while discarding the "diverging" suffix. See below for "abstract" example data.

```
Name                   Var1   Var2   Var3
AT&T                   22     12     3.5
AT&T Inc.              12     13     4.8
AT&T Inc.              22     45     4.8
AT&T Cap. Inc.         18     14     5.0
AT&T Hld. US           14     14     5.0
American Express       17     12     4.9
American Express Inc.  44     21     9.2
American Brands        44     21     9.2
Coca Cola Co           33     25     7.2
Coca Cola Botteling    38     12     9.4
```

Additionally think of a data structure like this.

I want to get to a "tidy" table like below to allow aggregation of data and computing statistics for each "most hierachical class".

```
    Name                   Var1   Var2   Var3
    AT&T                   22     12     3.5
    AT&T Inc.              12     13     4.8
    AT&T Inc.              22     45     4.8
    AT&T                   18     14     5.0
    AT&T                   14     14     5.0
    American Express       17     12     4.9
    American Express       44     21     9.2
    American Brands        44     21     9.2
    Coca Cola              33     25     7.2
    Coca Cola              38     12     9.4
```

The few "duplicates" I expect, as illustrated f.ex. with AT&T Inc. vs. AT&T can be checked manually.

I would highly appreciate any input, as I need to apply this logic to a data set with ~ 250k entries. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: In the example above, why do AT&T Cap. Inc. and AT&T Hld. US change to AT&T, but AT&T Inc. does not?

Comment: Only, because I don't think this is technically possible? I don't have I final list or data.table I can extract the common longest prefix from, thus I don't know beforehand how the data will look like. 

My rationale for this toy example data is that I think that only matching based on the longest shared prefix is possible. While Correct me if I am wrong! I would love to be wrong in this regard :)

If for example AT&T Hld US would be twice in the data set, I assumed that this would also stay in the data set as the name or longest prefix is shared

Comment: I don't get it! Wouldn't the longest shared prefix for the AT&T observations be just "AT&T" and not, "AT&T Inc." ? Anyway, this problem seems impossible to solve if not by writing regex expressions and parsing operations by hand. For example, you'd have to determine the prefixes yourself. If one were to do that automatically, that would be a Natural Language Processing task, which you could maybe solve by using a cluster algorithm.

Comment: The thing is, if that logic would apply, then both American Express and American Brand would become just American. I was afraid of that. Well, I'll probably stick to the current sample. 
And don't get me wrong here. Having all AT&T observations be transformed to just AT&T would be the ultimate goal here. (without any additionally required manual intervention) But, that would incur the aforementioned caveat of having both "American"-prefixed companies become just "American"

Comment: You're going to need some customized logic to make it work best for your use case -- as you point out, there's not really an algorithmic approach that won't consider `American Express` different from `American Brands` that would also fit your other requirements. You might try researching "entity matching" for more sophisticated approaches to this problem. One _ad hoc_ approach would be to (1) use `sort(table(unlist(strsplit(DT$Name, "\\s+"))))` and try and identify a set of "tags" like `Inc.` `US` `Co` etc that you are happy to strip from the end of the string, then apply that recursively.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Well, yeah. That's exaxtly my problem. And even with the ~250k entries coming down to just little over 2,500 unique 'firm names' (not firms as that's what I am trying to find out), it is still too labourous to handle it manually. 
Thanks for the neat idea though. Haven't thought of approaching my problem backwards. Always wanted to match the longest prefix from the names' start position. You might have just helped me to reduce my problem to a manageable chunk of manual work with your proposal! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps. It works for the cases you've given, but obviously you have to find words like "American" by hand. You might also want to look at the closest matches, say all the matches with match_length >= 1, and evaluate them by hand, instead of just choosing the best match. You could also look at the stringdist package and get the names that are close matches by longest common substring.

```
CJ.dt = function(X,Y) {
  stopifnot(is.data.table(X),is.data.table(Y))
  k = NULL
  X = X[, c(k=1, .SD)]
  setkey(X, k)
  Y = Y[, c(k=1, .SD)]
  setkey(Y, NULL)
  X[Y, allow.cartesian=TRUE][, k := NULL][]
}


mydata = data.table(name = c('American Express', 'American Express', 'American Brands',
                             'AT&T', 'AT&T Inc.', 'Coca Cola Co.', 'Coca Cola Bottling Co.',
                             'Abc', 'Abc Corp Suffix1', 'Abc Corp Suffix2'))
max_words = length(tstrsplit(mydata$name, ' '))

cartesianProduct = setkey(CJ.dt(mydata[, .(name)],mydata[, .(possible_match = name)]), name
                        )[name != possible_match
                        ][, paste0('name_word', 1:max_words) := tstrsplit(name, ' ')
                        ][, paste0('possible_match_word', 1:max_words) := tstrsplit(possible_match, ' ')]

first_words_that_dont_count = c('The', 'American', 'General')

strsplit_and_pad_NA = function(x, split) do.call(Map, c(c, tstrsplit(x, split)))
firstDifference = function(x, y) min(which(x != y | is.na(x) | is.na(y)), length(x) + 1)

cartesianProduct[, name_words := strsplit_and_pad_NA(name, ' ')
               ][, possible_match_words := strsplit_and_pad_NA(possible_match, ' ')
               ][, match_length := mapply(firstDifference, name_words, possible_match_words) - 1 #it's a match until the first one that's different, so you have to subtract 1
               ][, first_word := lapply(name_words, `[`, 1)
               ][match_length == 1 & first_word %in% first_words_that_dont_count, match_length := 0
               ][, best_match := frank(-match_length, ties.method =  'random') == 1 & match_length != 0, name
               ][, to_subset_names := lapply(match_length, function(x) seq_len(x))
               ][, name_without_suffix := lapply(Map(`[`, name_words, to_subset_names), paste, collapse = ' ')]

mydata[cartesianProduct[best_match == TRUE & name != name_without_suffix],
       name_without_suffix := i.name_without_suffix,
       on = .(name)]
```

Comment: Thanks mate for that awesome proposal! Still looking through all and trying to conceptualize everything first before I apply it for testing tomorrow. Defintely helps a lot and it's a great treasure trove to get me started with the task at hand. Much obliged Nathan!

Comment: @aimbotter21 Glad to help, let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: On first sight, all looks great and it seemingly works for my data! Quite thrilled. Took roughly 10 min to compute the initial cartesian product that was quite large as a reuslt of the CJ with all possible variations. (from ~2,800 firms to ~7.8m entries in the cartesian product data.table. However, I noted that careful consideration has to go into the creation of the **first words that dont count** list as that ultimately scales the accuracy/matching rate in the final data assignment where you compare to name to the best match in the CJ

Comment: I found numerous more of such first words that shouldn't count for prefix matching such as *Bank, Central, Consolidated, Continental* etc. just to name a few and reached a sizable reduction of my data set, that would otherwise not have been feasible. Trying to finetune that list even further and still trying to get my head around of all that you are doing in your code, but a great working solution for me. 

Ultimately, it is nearly impossible to quickly gauge the accuracy of the computed output as I don't have data to compare it too, but the aggregated data offers more insight than before!